# magit commit does not permit adding a gpg signature

Tags: magit, osx, gpg, debug

I am **failing to run gpg to sign commits**, after doing so successfully before an upgrade to Mojave and an upgrade to Emacs.  (I am not sure when I lost the ability to sign files in the past year.)

When I attempt to sign commits now this happens:

```
GitError! failed to write commit object  [Type `$' for details]
```

When I expand the '$' for details, I get this:

```
  0 git … commit --amend --only
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
[master e61729b] Master SQLite DB in ~/ingest.
 Date: Tue Sep 17 17:35:07 2019 -0500
 2 files changed, 70 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)

128 git … commit --amend --only
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
error: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

My searches for fixes related to GNU gpg and the new Transient library and suggestions for that switchover in the Magit source have not led to a solution.

### **What I am looking for**

I am interested in determining

- How Emacs finds the paths to use gpg in Magit to run this command so
  that I can debug the configuration.  **Answered** in the comment,    incorporated below:

  (setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin"))
  (setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
- How can I see where the paths are that Emacs and GPG can use
  internally when running any command?

I am interested in the solutions that others have had to this issue.

### Versions of software and OS.

```
magit-version returns the following string

Magit 2.90.1 Git 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117), Emacs 26.1, darwin
on an iMac Pro (2017) running OS X 10.14.6

Version of Emacs: Emacs 26.1 (9.0)
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs
```

**Additional information - Added 2019-09-20 Friday**

I solved the above issue with this correction:

[Emacs EPA and Gnupg2 no usable configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741477/emacs-epa-and-gnupg2-no-usable-configuration)

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
```

Comment: I think magit just tells git to run gpg (i.e., Emacs never runs gpg directly for this use case), so only `(getenv "PATH")` should be relevant.

Comment: `I solved the above issue with this correction` Please post an answer describing how you fixed the issue. `New issue: ...` Please post that as an independent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `error: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory`

This means "I cannot find gpg and therefore cannot run it", i.e. that `gpg` either isn't installed at all (which is unlikely) or that it is not located on the `PATH` where processes look for executables they intend to run as subprocesses.

Based on what you have posted above that directory happens to be `/usr/local/bin`, which is a directory that should really be placed on `PATH`; it isn't obscure at all.

To teach `emacs` about that directory the `exec-path` lisp variable has to be used, to teach other processes (including `git`) to do so the environment variable `PATH` has to be set. Something like:

```elisp
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the administrative oversight to post the answer separately. I will post the issue with Magit and viewing signatures as a separate issue.